# What is the best way to save a string-array in SQLite on Android?

Tags: android, arrays, sqlite

One string size is about 200 bytes,
and it stores 10~20 size in a daily array.
(Store 10~20 strings of 200bytes, as array type)

I have found a way to convert an array to a string
and store it in SQLite.
However, I do not know it's a good idea
because the size of the string is large.

1.
If large arrays of strings, 
is it a good idea to store arrays as a string?

2.
or is there a better way?

I would like advice. Thank you.

Comment: In a table, one row per element.

Comment: See https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html.

Answer (score 0):

You're actually placing your concern onto the wrong part of your database design.

For SQLite, the [maximum length of a String](https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html) is 1 billion bytes, so your worries about your 10-20 strings of 200 bytes each actually isn't considered that large.

There's really no harm in storing your array as a single long String in your database. Especially when it's nowhere close to the maximum limit of a String.

Your database query time won't become longer due to your String being long. The real concern here is the processing you'll be doing on that String to turn it back into an Array. Typically, if the String is extremely long, the real performance hit is when you're flattening the array into a String and when you're transforming that String back into an Array.

However, typically, this is something you'll show a loading indicator for to your users.

For storing an Array into a database, there's really only two ways to do so:

- Flatten array into a single String and store the String as TEXT
- Create a table meant to store the individual elements of the string, and include a column for a Foreign Key that allows you to associate those rows with the same array. Then you'll store each element of your String arrays as a row in this table.

Depending on what you need, one design is better than the other.

For example, you would normally prefer the second implementation if your app requires you to constantly edit individual elements of an array.

For such an example, it wouldn't make much sense to use the first solution, because this means every time you want to edit the contents of an array, you'll be fetching back the complete array in it's entirety. This is impractical when you only want to fetch or edit a particular portion of that String.

Therefore, in such an example, it is much more practical to store the individual elements of the arrays into individual rows of a Table meant for this type of data. You'll be querying only the row you want and updating only the row you want.

So to answer your questions, there's really only two ways to store your String array as a TEXT type in your SQLite database. Both ways work and the real concern is to consider which solution fits your needs best.

If your app only requires you to store and fetch the array in it's entirety each time, then the single String method might be more preferable.

But if your app requires you to work with individual elements of your array, then using the table method would be more convenient.